# Python / Pandas Comparing records on column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, compare

All,

I have a csv file of about 16k users. I am trying to compare each user record by their access. I want to find out how many users have the exact same combos of access. Not only I want to find this out but I want to return it so I can analyze it further.

A users access will look like this (access1|access2|access3|12345|855|specialaccess|etc.|etc|). Users have different lengths of access too.

I have come up with something that I THINK works lol. I just want to know what the best route is to find this type of data. I want to make sure if there is a better way to compare each users access lists.

```
access= users_with_access["access"]

access_dups = pd.DataFrame(users_with_roles[access.isin(access[access.duplicated()])].sort_values("usersjobcode"))
```

#### Edit *** - Here is some sample / example data.

```
users = {'UserName': ['Bob Ross','Darth Vader','John Henry','Dolph Lungren', 'Simon Riley', 'John Price'],
         'UserID': ['bross', 'dvader', 'jhenry', 'dlung', 'simri', 'jprice'],
        'Access': ['access1|access2|site1|site3|testing|etc|8556','access30|access3|access2|access1','access1|access2|site1|access3','access1|access2|access3|site1', 'access1|access2|site1', 'access2|access1|site1']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['UserName', 'UserID', 'Access'])
print (df)
```

Comment: Can you put a small data sample?

Comment: users = {'UserName': ['Bob Ross','Darth Vader','John Henry','Dolph Lungren', 'Simon Riley', 'John Price'],
         'UserID': ['bross', 'dvader', 'jhenry', 'dlung', 'simri', 'jprice'],
        'Access': ['access1|access2|site1|site3|testing|etc|8556','access30|access3|access2|access1','access1|access2|site1|access3','access1|access2|access3|site1', 'access1|access2|site1', 'access2|access1|site1']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['UserName', 'UserID', 'Access'])
print (df)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Case 1

If you care about the order of the access items for each user you can use a **pandas.DataFrame.groupby** instruction. For example with your sample data and three more users to have some duplicated access in two cases an one with same items but in different order:

```py
users = {'UserName': ['Bob Ross',
                      'Darth Vader',
                      'John Henry',
                      'Dolph Lungren',
                      'Simon Riley',
                      'John Price',
                      'Jhon Doe',
                      'Jane Doe',
                      'Pedro Perez'
                     ],
         'UserID': ['bross',
                    'dvader',
                    'jhenry',
                    'dlung',
                    'simri',
                    'jprice',
                    'jdoe',
                    'jadoe',
                    'pperez'
                   ],
         'Access': ['access1|access2|site1|site3|testing|etc|8556',
                    'access30|access3|access2|access1',
                    'access1|access2|site1|access3',
                    'access1|access2|access3|site1', 
                    'access1|access2|site1',
                    'access2|access1|site1',
                    'access1|access2|site1|site3|testing|etc|8556',
                    'access1|access2|site1|site3|testing|8556|etc',
                    'access30|access3|access2|access1',
                   ]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(users, columns = ['UserName', 'UserID', 'Access'])
df
```

[image: dataframe]

To get the number of users with exactly the same access (same order) use groupby by this way. Note the access value with two users:

```
df.groupby(['Access']).agg({'UserID': 'count'})
```

[image]

To get the name of users with exactly the same access (same order) use groupby by this way. Note that each access values list all the users in group and the count must be one if there is not duplicated users::

```
df.groupby(['Access', 'UserName']).agg({'UserID': 'count'})
```

[image]

### Case 2

If you don't care about the order of the access items will be useful to split the items

```
df['Access'].apply(lambda x : x.split('|'))

[Out x]:

0    [access1, access2, site1, site3, testing, etc,...
1                [access30, access3, access2, access1]
2                   [access1, access2, site1, access3]
3                   [access1, access2, access3, site1]
4                            [access1, access2, site1]
5                            [access2, access1, site1]
6    [access1, access2, site1, site3, testing, etc,...
7    [access1, access2, site1, site3, testing, 8556...
8                [access30, access3, access2, access1]
```

Or something like that that: split the string in a list, convert to set to preserve only unique values, then convert again to list to be sorted:

```
 df['SortedAccess'] = df['Access'].apply(
     lambda x : '|'.join(sorted(list(set(x.split('|'))))))
```

[image: split item access]

And then groupby again.

```
df.groupby(['SortedAccess']).agg({'UserID': 'count'})
```

[image]

```
df.groupby(['SortedAccess', 'UserName']).agg({'UserID': 'count'})
```

[image]

Comment: Augusto thank you!! So I dont really care about the order of access. I am primarly concerned with who has the exact same access. My goal is to analyze the common groups of access so we can create baseline access for those users since they have the same access. So I guess splitting them up and then comparing would be the best route?

Comment: Thanks again Augusto! Really appreciate it.

Comment: Also, I keep seeing this lambda thing being used quite often. I need to learn more about it :) seems like it is very usefull. I am very new to all of this .

Comment: Scott, If you consider that it is an answer to your question. Don't forget to accept it. And maybe add some tags or expand the description of your question for future users.